# Combining Collinear Variables

Tags: multicollinearity, predictor

I have a set of 10 variables: 9 explanatory, 1 response.  I wish to do a constrained regression on the variables and use the values of the coefficients as weights in a TOPSIS analysis.
I am having several issues with this - but I think the biggest one is that the variables are slightly collinear (If I run an unconstrained regression with these variables I'm getting VIFs of ~6)
Since I don't want to delete variables, is it acceptable to combine them?  What are good ways to combine variables that have different scales (Example:  variables are # of rebounds and # of blocks,  and Field Goal% vs. Rebounds).  I was thinking I could combine rebounds and blocks by multiplying them together and that may work for positively correlated variables,  would it work for negative correlated ones as well? 
Thanks!!

Comment: While there isn't really any 'bright line' b/t problematic & non-problematic multicollinearity, a common rule of thumb is to worry when your VIFs are >=10. Multicollinearity may not be your problem.